# Pdf horizontal scrolling

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, horizontal-scrolling

I need a component, including commercial licence, for c# that only view a pdf file (no print, no save, no copy, only for read) with horizontal page change, like a book. I have tried a multitude of components, but none gives me the ability to change the pages with horizontal scrolling mouse or touchscreen interface. I tried with axAcroPdf, trying to recognize the gesture scroll, but unfortunately it seems that the component does not support mousemove and mouseclick events.
has anyone found a solution?

thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please give people more information about your problem. Read [FAQ] and [ask]